# Select row unless value is canceled by another row

Tags: mysql

```
FROM    TO     TYPE   
----   ----    ----
John   Jane    Like
Jill   Jane    Like
Jane   John    Hide
```

How would I write a SELECT statement like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE to='Jane' UNLESS from='Jane' AND type='hide'
```

Such that in the table above, it would return John and Jill, minus John since Jane had chosen to hide John, meaning that only Jill would be returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.to = 'Jane' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.from = t.to and t2.type = 'Hide'
                 );
```

Comment: I think you mean `t2.to = t.from`